# C++ operator overloading constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

**Can some one explain how below program becomes infinte loop of "AabAabAab.."**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(int j=1):i(j)
    {cout<<"B";}
private:
    int i;
};

class Case{
public:
    Case(int j=1):i(j) {cout<<"A";}
    operator Base() { cout<<"ab"; return *(new Case); }
private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Base obj = Case();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it runs fine on vc++ editor..just compiled.

Comment: wow. that would make a nice interview question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Base obj = Case();
```

This calls the `Case` default constructor, printing `A`. Then, there is a conversion to `Base` via this operator, which has an infinite recursion:

```
operator Base() { cout<<"ab"; return *(new Case); }
```

Because it attempts to return a `Case` instance (prints `abA`), which must be converted to `Base`, which invokes the conversion operator, which creates a `Case` instance (prints `abA`), which must be converter to `Base`, which...

Answer (score 2):

> Can some one explain how below program becomes infinte loop of "AabAabAab.."

Not really infinite. This will eventually crash your program because of stack overflow. This is what's going on. Here:

```
Base obj = Case();
```

You are creating a temporary object of type `Case` and using it to initialize an object of type `Base`.

The only way this can be done is by picking the user-defined conversion operator of `Case`, which can return a `Base`.

Now this conversion operator in turn happens to create a temporary object of type `Case`, from which the return value of the operator should be initialized.:

```
return *(new Case);
```

Since the return value is itself of type `Base`, the temporary now has to be converted to an object of type `Base` - and since the temporary has type `Case`, the same user-defined conversion operator is invoked again.

This is what attempts to generate an infinite recursion. Since each function call requires creating a stack frame, however, your neverending recursion will eventually cause a stack overflow, and your process will be terminated.